# SQL Server Agent - BCryptDecrypt failed

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2016 and in the SQL Server Agent event log, I have thousands of error's with the following message:

```
Date        26/12/2019 3:47:06 PM
Log     SQL Server Agent (Current - 16/12/2019 4:28:00 PM)

Message
[442] BCryptDecrypt failed (-1073741762).
```

I can't find anything that relates to this error and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong that I can see except for the message - does anyone know what it is and how I could potentially fix it?

Thank you

Comment: -1073741762 == 0xC000003E == STATUS_DATA_ERROR. Probably SQL Agent is failing to decrypt credentials to run a particular job (e.g.: proxy credentials for SSIS). Start by investigating which jobs are scheduled to start around the failure times and see if you can start them manually - the one(s) which fail need their credentials fixed.

Comment: thanks AlwaysLearning - i've only got 6 scheduled jobs in my Agent and 1 is disabled - i went through the list of jobs and they all run fine. i wish it told you where the error was coming from

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

We use to use managed backups to Azure blob for our DB's - we canned this method for our on prem servers and went another path - however when we swapped over we didn't disable managed backups on the server and we deleted our storage account within Azure. This in return was throwing these weird errors up. 
You can't disable managed backup's on your DB's if your storage account in Azure is gone - i had to recreate the storage account with the same naming convention and recreate the blob - update the SAS key in your credentials - then you can disable managed backups.

Hope this helps others.