# BCryptDecrypt failed (-1073741762)

Tags: sql-server

I am experiencing this issue as well.

Date        6/18/2021 10:06:40 AM
Log         SQL Server Agent (Archive #2 - 6/18/2021 11:08:00 AM)

Message
[442] BCryptDecrypt failed (-1073741762).

Do we know when would this trigger and why? This led to the very high memory utilization and my DB server was on brink to get crashed.

Comment: It appears that you have some agent job that uses BCryptDecrypt in some fashion. You will need to find this job and debug the jobsteps / code that it uses.

Comment: [SQL Server Agent - BCryptDecrypt failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59486333/sql-server-agent-bcryptdecrypt-failed) offers no insights?