# BCryptDecrypt failed in SQL Server Agent log

Tags: sql-server

Noticing the error

> [442] BCryptDecrypt failed (-1073741762)

in my SQL Server agent log. Please advise how to resolve this and what else to check.

I am unable to find which job is giving this error. The error occurrence is at random dates and time.

Comment: Any clues in the previous SO question, [SQL Server Agent - BCryptDecrypt failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59486333)?

Comment: no did not relate to the clues of the above post.